# how to add a custom class in table row in LDS?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning component which contains a table.

I am trying to highlight a row in red if some conditions are met.

My code is like this

```
<tr aura:id="tablerow" >
</tr>
```

I have added this in my css

```
.THIS .row-removal {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.THIS .slds-table tbody tr td .row-removal {
    background-color: red !important; 
}
```

and in my controller I am doing something this this

```
if(conditionMet)
$A.util.addClass(component.find("tablerow"), "row-removal");
```

When I inspect element I can see the class row-removal has been added but nothing happens.

If I do the same thing on a  it works.

Is there any restriction from SF that custom classes can not be added to table rows ?

Answer (score 2):

To properly target the element/node you should instead be using the following selector:

```
.THIS tr.row-removal{
    background-color: red;
}
```

using `!important` is not considered a best practice.

tested and works, using this [SLDS Blueprint of tables](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#site-main-content).

```
<tbody>
<tr class="slds-hint-parent row-removal">
  <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">Cloudhub</a></div>
  </th>....
```

css:

```
.THIS tr.row-removal{
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image]